# Any easy way of 'visible for all breakpoints but not for 'xs' in twitter-bootstrap-3'

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new with bootstrap.

While reading documentation I noticed that it is posible to set a class for a default invisible object to make it visible for some breakpoints like `visible-xs`, `visible-md` that is OK.

But what if I want to hide a default visible object for only one breakpoint. Do I have to add all classes `visible-sm visible-md visible-lg` classes to hide it in `xs` screens? Or is there any easy way  like `invisible-xs`? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.hidden-xs
```

will hide your content for all divices under 768px resolution.
check out the table at bootstrap website http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: OMG I dont know why but I was looking for keyword `invisible` as opposite of visible. keyword `hidden` did not cross my mind. Thank you.

Comment: In Bootstrap 3.3.4 (and probably prior to that) the class 'invisible' does not act the same as 'hidden'. 'invisible' will hide the object, while keeping the space the object takes on screen. To the contrary 'hidden' will remove the object, including the space it takes on screen.